# Ajax & PHP register / login form validation suggestions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

Currently I try to make a Ajax & PHP registration / login form, it works but there are certain validation issues.

I use `password_hash();` but I can only validate it with `password_verify();` in my php file. So my idea was that both Jquery and php sends callbacks in case of failure. There could be something that I can validate with PHP but not Jquery (for what I know)

**Jquery**

```
if(username == "") {
    $(".callbackDiv").html("username is empty");
    return false;
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(!password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) {
    // error message
    return false;
}
```

So basicly I would like a way where if Jquery doesn't validate it and sends a callback, PHP steps in instead and sends a callback somehow?
Or Maybe there is an easier way that I do not know of?

Comment: Can you post also your JS code that makes the AJAX request?

Comment: if you are using ajax to send login inputs so if validation failed on server-side you would need to return back a json object like `{Success:true , ValidationFailed : true , Message : "User Name or Password is incorrect "} `

Comment: Thanks Matt.k.
I have never worked with JSON but found some tutorials and it is exactly what I needed! Works like a charm.